# Java process yielding priority to other windows processes

Tags: java, windows, multithreading

I have been tasked with creating a custom File Backup Service that would allow any laptops utilizing this service to back up certain directories upon connecting to our network server. A requirement that I was given is that the service should basically yield priority to the User's normal activity on that laptop and not hinder performance... too much. I have created this program in Java with the intention of wrapping it as a service with YAJSW. I know that I can set the "Process Priority" to LOW, which would allow:

> The threads of the process are preempted by the threads of any process running in a higher priority level.

Because of this, I was thinking that I would utilize a thread per file transfer with the idea that these threads would do just that. I currently have something like this:

```
public void copyFiles() {
    for (ScannedFile file : filesToCopy) {
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                fileCopyUsingStreams(file);
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

However, I am not sure that this will actually work the way that I am thinking. I was also thinking as an alternative to this, that I could run these threads sequentially in hopes of improving the chance of the "yield of priority". I am looking for any ideas and improvements that you all could lend. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I feel that you're on the right track.  However, there will be a limit somewhere as to how many threads you should create.  This may be the I/O on the laptop, the network I/O or your server.  I'd make sure you limit the number of threads in some way - maybe even a configurable parameter.

In this context you won't really need to worry about the Java thread priority since that is juggling priorities within the JVM.

Comment: That is a very good point that I overlooked regarding the thread limit. Thank you.